# Convert mibibyte-days to gibibyte-months.

Tags: fractions

I have a web host that charges $1 for every Gibibyte (1024 MiB) that I use per month.

Currently I am using about 7.6 MiB (Mibibytes) per day.

I tried to do this myself and ended up with hopelessly large numbers that I didn't know the meaning of.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm trying to find out how much I will be charged each month...

Comment: $\frac {7.6 \cdot 30}{1024} \approx \$0.2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If you are using 7.6 MiB per day, then you will use 7.6*30 MiB every 30-day month.

Now use that number and the fraction (1 dollar/1024MiB) do get your answer. It shouldn't be that big.

Comment: I must have been multiplying by 1024 instead of dividing. Thank you.

Comment: @Computer_ACE If you perform dimensional analysis then it should become clear when to divide vs. multiply.

Comment: dimensional analysis?

Comment: Do they teach that in algebra 1?

Comment: http://www.chem.tamu.edu/class/fyp/mathrev/mr-da.html